# SqlBulkCopy alternative on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm developing this Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UploadCodes]
    @param1 nvarchar(20),           
    @param2 nvarchar(20),           
    @param3 nvarchar(20),               
    @param4 nvarchar(20),               
    @param5 nvarchar(20),           
    @newCodes as dbo.CodeList READONLY  
AS
    declare @code nvarchar(20),
            @codeLevel tinyint,
            @headerId int,
            @productId int;

    set nocount on;
    Begin transaction
        -- Insert china header file.
        Insert into CODES_HEADER
                values (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5);

        -- If an error, end here.
        If (@@ERROR != 0)
        Begin
            rollback transaction
            return -1 -- Database error
        End

        -- Get header id from latest insert.
        set @headerId = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY());

        -- Get product's id.
        set @productId = (select Id from PRODUCTS where PRODUCT_CODE = @param3)

        -- If this product doesn't exist on database, insert it.
        if (@productId is null)
        begin
            Insert into PRODUCTS values (@param3);

            -- If an error, end here.
            If (@@ERROR != 0)
            Begin
                rollback transaction
                return -1 -- Database error
            End

            set @productId = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY());
        end

        set @codeLevel = (select CAST(@param1 as tinyint));

        Create table #tempCodes (
                Code nvarchar(20))

        insert into #tempCodes (Code) select CODE from @newCodes;

        set rowcount 1
        select @code = Code from #tempCodes

        -- Loop all child codes to check if they have a parent.
        while @@rowcount <> 0
        begin
            set rowcount 0
            select * from #tempCodes where Code = @code
            delete #tempCodes where Code = @code

            insert into EXTERNAL_CODES(CODE, CODE_LEVEL, CODES_HEADER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
                values (@code, @codeLevel, @headerId, @productId);

            -- If an error, end here.
            If (@@ERROR != 0)
            Begin
                rollback transaction
                return -1 -- Database error
            End

            -- Get next code.
            set rowcount 1
            select @code = Code from #tempCodes
        end
        set rowcount 0

    Commit transaction
return 0
```

This is the definition of `dbo.CodeList` type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CodeList]
AS TABLE
(
  CODE nvarchar(20)
);
```

My problem is with its loop, it gets too long when there are a lot of codes.

Is there another way to run it faster?

On `C#` I use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't know if there is something similar on SQL. I have found [Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188365.aspx) but it uses a file.

Comment: Have you considered trying to rewrite your loop into a query?

Comment: No, I don't have enough sql knowledge to do that.

Comment: It looks like you're pulling out one code from #tempCodes at a time, and for each such row you add one row to EXTERNAL_CODES, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I have to insert all #tempCodes values into EXTERNAL_CODES table. But I need codeLevel, headerId, productId for each EXTERNAL_CODES row.

Comment: Note that your query also does one other thing, it issues a `select * from #tempCodes where Code = @code` for each iteration, is this necessary?

Comment: I don't know. I have copied this code from an example and I haven't check it what it does. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite the entire loop into a single insert statement.

This:

```
set rowcount 1
select @code = Code from #tempCodes

-- Loop all child codes to check if they have a parent.
while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    set rowcount 0
    select * from #tempCodes where Code = @code
    delete #tempCodes where Code = @code

    insert into EXTERNAL_CODES(CODE, CODE_LEVEL, CODES_HEADER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
        values (@code, @codeLevel, @headerId, @productId);

    -- If an error, end here.
    If (@@ERROR != 0)
    Begin
        rollback transaction
        return -1 -- Database error
    End

    -- Get next code.
    set rowcount 1
    select @code = Code from #tempCodes
end
set rowcount 0
```

Does this:

1. Pick out a single code from #tempCodes into @code
2. Delete that code from #tempCodes
3. Insert one row into EXTERNAL_CODES, using that @code + other variables
4. Grab the next and go back to step #2.

You can rewrite that entire loop into this query (basically everything I pasted above):

```
INSERT INTO EXTERNAL_CODES (CODE, CODE_LEVEL, CODES_HEADER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
SELECT Code, @codeLevel, @headerId, @productID FROM #tempCodes
```

If you also need to clear out #tempCodes (which I doubt), you would also issue this statement:

```
DELETE #tempCodes
```

If you also need to rollback other changes if the above fails you would add that single if-statement with a rollback in here as well

Comment: Maybe, I don't need `#tempCodes` and I can use `newCodes` instead because I don't need to delete any code from it. This should make it faster.

Comment: In general, avoid writing imperative code when talking to your database engine, always try to come up with query-based statements instead, it's what the database engine is optimized for and in general the people writing the database engine is way better at optimizing these things than we mere mortals are.

Comment: Imperative code is code that is written like any other programming language, with if-statements, loops, etc. Query-based code uses inserts, deletes, updates, etc.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've just tested it and it is very very fast.

Comment: Following your answer I have to do an `Update` instead of an `Insert`. I have asked this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773219/update-topn-from-select, because I need to update N rows, and this value is also in on a table parameter.