# How to update N rows when N is in a from (select N from @myVar)

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing this stored procedure on SQL Server 2012.

The stored procedure will update `Quantity` rows in `EXTERNAL_CODES` table for each row in `@newBatches` parameter. It's like a loop, I will need to create a new row in `BATCHES` table for each row in `@newBatches` parameter.

And then, I have to update `Quantity` rows in `EXTERNAL_CODES` table with each `batchId` created.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateBatchAndKeepExternalCodes]
      @newBatches as dbo.CreateBatchList READONLY,
      @productId int
AS
    set nocount on;

    declare @lowestCodeLevel tinyint;

-- ======== VALIDATION ==========
    if ((select count(name) from @newBatches) = 0)
        return -112;

-- ====== CODE ========

    -- Get lowest aggregation level.
    set @lowestCodeLevel = 
        (select min(c.application_code)
            from CHINA_CODES_HEADER c, PRODUCTS p
            where p.Id = @productId and c.DRUG_TEN_SEATS = p.PRODUCT_CODE);

    begin transaction;

        insert into BATCHES (PRODUCT_ID, NAME, CREATED)
            select @productId, Name, CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as nvarchar(50))
              from @newBatches;

        update top(t.Quantity) EXTERNAL_CODES 
           set BATCH_ID = (select ID from BATCHES where NAME = t.Name)
             , USED = 1
         from (select Name, Quantity from @newBatches) t
         where PRODUCT_ID = @productId and CODE_LEVEL = @lowestCodeLevel;

    commit transaction;

RETURN 0
```

I get an error on this `update`:

```
update top(t.Quantity) EXTERNAL_CODES 
  set BATCH_ID = (select ID from BATCHES where NAME = t.Name)
    , USED = 1
from (select Name, Quantity from @newBatches) t
where PRODUCT_ID = @productId and CODE_LEVEL = @lowestCodeLevel;
```

The error is here: `update top(t.Quantity)`. It can't find `t.Quantity`.

`dbo.CreateBatchList` is:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CreateBatchList] AS TABLE
(
    Name nVARCHAR(20),
    Quantity int
)
```

My problem is that I can't set to update `Quantity` rows. Any idea?

The error (or warning) message is:

> SQL71005: The reference to the column t.Quantity could not be resolved.

Maybe I could use `MERGE`.

Comment: I think the problem is that `t.Quantity` is potentially different for each row in the from clause. besides, there is no meaning to `top` without `order by`.

Comment: The error (or warning) message is: SQL71005: The reference to the column t.Quantity could not be resolved.

Comment: because it's a part of the from clause, meaning that it's decided for each row in the update. the number in `top(number)` should be a number that is decided **before** the update statement...

Comment: So, what do I have to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement is quite confusing. If for instance `@newBatches` table has multiple lines, then you are saying, pick all the `Quantity` from `@newBatches` in `Top`?

Anyway, I think the solution is to use a loop to use each line from `@newBatches` to update. I have modified your code in order to test it on my side, and have replaced all the tables with Table Variables. You may find it helpful.

But still without any `Order By` clause and without knowing actual business logic, I can't say this solution is correct.

```
DECLARE @productID int;
DECLARE @lowestCodeLevel int;

DECLARE @EXTERNAL_CODES table(BATCH_ID varchar(100), USED bit, PRODUCT_ID int, CODE_LEVEL int);
DECLARE @BATCHES table(ID int, NAME varchar(100));
DECLARE @newBatches table(Name nVARCHAR(20), Quantity int);



-- we don't know at this point whether @newBatches has some column
-- through which we can uniquely identify a row
-- that is why we are creating this new table in which we have Row_ID column
-- through which we can extract each line
DECLARE @newBatchesWithRowID table(Row_ID int not null identity, Name nVarchar(20), Quantity int);

INSERT INTO @newBatchesWithRowID(Name, Quantity)
    SELECT  Name, Quantity
    FROM    @newBatches;

DECLARE @prvRow_ID int;

-- loop to iterate in @newBatchesWithRowID table
WHILE(1 = 1)
Begin
    DECLARE @row_ID int = NULL;
    DECLARE @Name varchar(100);
    DECLARE @Quantity int;

    SELECT  TOP 1 @row_ID = Row_ID
            , @Quantity = Quantity
            , @Name = Name
    FROM    @newBatchesWithRowID
    WHERE   Row_ID > @prvRow_ID OR @prvRow_ID IS NULL
    ORDER BY Row_ID;
    If @row_ID IS NULL Break;
    SET @prvRow_ID = @row_ID;

    update top(@Quantity) @EXTERNAL_CODES 
        set BATCH_ID = (select ID from @BATCHES where NAME = @Name)
        , USED = 1
    where PRODUCT_ID = @productId and CODE_LEVEL = @lowestCodeLevel;
END
```